# Multiple Category Nested Query Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've followed this code structure for a multi-level category system on Laravel 5:

This works fine. But I'm trying to put together a query to return posts in a category (by slug) but also the children categories underneath.

So heres what I've got at the moment:

```
    $posts = Post::with('images')->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($slug)
    {
        $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);

    })->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

This returns everything under the category that matches the slug passed through, but not the children. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you have a subcategory of a subcategory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one depth of subcategories, the following solution is what I would use.

```
<?php
$category = Category::where('slug',$slug)->first();
$posts = Post::with('images')->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($category)
{
    $q->where(function($q) use ($category) {
      $q->where('id', $category->id)->orWhere('parent_id',$category->id);
    });
})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Comment: I think this is close, and the logic seems right, but it appears to be returning all posts. This is the generated query: `select * from 'posts' where 'posts'.'deleted_at' is null and (select count(*) from 'categories' inner join 'category_post' on 'categories'.'id' = 'category_post'.'category_id' where 'category_post'.'post_id' = 'posts'.'id' and 'id' = '9' or 'parent_id' = '9' and 'categories'.'deleted_at' is null) >= 1 order by 'created_at' desc limit 10 offset 0` - however I think there needs to be brackets around the id and parent_id... so (`id` = '9' or `parent_id` = '9'). Any ideas?

Comment: Since it's using a join, it messes with the query slightly. I edited my answer to group the conditions properly to avoid the ungrouped comparison with the OR operator.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you only fetched the `Post`s and their `images`. If I understood correctly, what you want to fetch are the `Post`s, their `images`, the `category` their in and `childCategories` (this is a made up name) of that `category`. You just need to add `category.childCategories` in your `with` method like so:

```php
$posts = Post::with('images', 'categories.childCategories')->whereHas('categories', function($q) use ($slug)
{
    $q->where('slug', '=', $slug);

})->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);
```

Remember to change the `childCategories` name to whatever the child category relationship name in your `Category` model.

Comment: Hello, I want to retrieve the posts from categories and subcategories. So the concept from dboskovic however, that solution returns all posts at the moment.